# Angular - get data from Object Array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, object

Good morning, can anyone advise me? I'm pretty clueless. I've already spent a few hours on it and I don't know how to solve this.

The data is fictitious and the original JSON is far more complex.

**JSON**

```
   {
    "main": [
        [
            {
                "type": "dasdasdasd",
                "id": 5,
                "content": {
                    "title": "adadadsad",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-02-02T11:23:00Z",
                            "id": 12,
                            "name": "test",
                            "isEnabled": false,
                            "isHighlited": false,
                            "images": {
                                "lists": {
                                    "small": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 18,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "original": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 19,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "large": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 22,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                           
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "medium": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 23,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                            
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "enum": "LINIE",
                            "url": "https://test.com"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "second": [
    ]
}
```

How can I get from main -> content -> items -> images -> url?
More precisely each images and from that url.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: in this case to get the small image url (if I followed correctly..lol), it would be `main[0].content.items[0].images.lists.small[0].url` where 0 is the index of the item in the array. You can also use a site like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to view the JSON breakdown

Comment: Y but i need every image, means : URL of large, smal, medium etc..

Comment: Are you sure `main` should be a doubly nested array?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your main array has an array as 1st element. If that is correct, you take the first element of main, and then loop over that.

```js
let jsonObj = {
    "main": [
        [
            {
                "type": "dasdasdasd",
                "id": 5,
                "content": {
                    "title": "adadadsad",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "date": "2012-02-02T11:23:00Z",
                            "id": 12,
                            "name": "test",
                            "isEnabled": false,
                            "isHighlited": false,
                            "images": {
                                "lists": {
                                    "small": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 18,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "original": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 19,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "large": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 22,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                           
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "medium": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 23,
                                            "position": 0,
                                            "titleImage": true,
                                            "url": "",
                                            "thumbnailReady": true
                                            
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "enum": "LINIE",
                            "url": "https://test.com"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "second": [
    ]
}

let smallImg = "", originalImg = "", largeImg = "", mediumImg = "";
jsonObj.main[0].forEach(mainItem => {
  mainItem.content.items.forEach(item => {
    smallImg = item.images.lists.small[0].url;
    originalImg = item.images.lists.original[0].url;
    largeImg = item.images.lists.large[0].url;
    mediumImg = item.images.lists.medium[0].url;
  });
});
console.log(smallImg);
console.log(originalImg);
console.log(largeImg);
console.log(mediumImg);
```